# Dynamically change the button name

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button, it consists of a name and an icon. I want to dynamically change the name of the button, but do not touch the icon. How can I do it?
`innerHTML` `innerText` change completely, they don’t fit

```
<button>
   NameButton
    <svg>
    </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: Wrap the name in `span` or `div` element they change them

Comment: "but do not touch the icon." Perhaps you did mean don't replace the icon. Yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap text into span tag and use childNode to change

```js
document.querySelector("button").childNodes[1].textContent="Something"
```

```html
<button>
   <span>NameButton</span>
    <svg>
    
    </svg>
</button>
```

or Without Wrapping into span

```js
document.querySelector("button").childNodes[0].textContent="Something2"
```

```html
<button>
   NameButton
    <svg>
    
    </svg>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the name in span or div element then try to change the name ..

**HTML**

```
<button id="buttonid">
   <span>NameButton<span>
    <svg>
    </svg>
</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function changeName(btnid, value){
    var btn = document.querySelctor("#"+btnid+" span");
    btn.innerHTML = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to just leave:

```
<button>NameButton</button>
```

which is the most semantic way, and add the svg icon in CSS

```
button:after {
    background-image: url('my-file.svg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to simply wrap the text in a `span`, as mentioned in other answers. However, if for whatever reason, you insist on not doing that, then you need to dig into the button's `childNodes`, and change the `textContent` of the first one (which is the text node).

```js
document.querySelector('button').childNodes[0].textContent = "Hellow";
```

```html
<button>
   NameButton
    <svg>
    </svg>
</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

First extract the svg, then change the text, then add the svg back in.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('b');
let svg = btn.children[0]
btn.textContent = "changed";
btn.appendChild(svg);
```

```html
<button id="b">
   NameButton
    <svg>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
    </svg>
</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how you do it correctly using `TextNode.prototype.wholeText`:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const buttonTextNode = button.childNodes[0];
button.removeChild(button.childNodes[0]);
button.insertBefore(new Text(buttonTextNode.wholeText.replace(buttonTextNode.wholeText, 'NewNameForTheButton')), button.firstElementChild);
```

```html
<button>
   NameButton
  <br /><span>untouched</span>
</button>
```

This will not affect the other child elements of the button at all.